# list index out of range - in shell works

Tags: django

the problem is when I want to take out the value from Models.

I type:

```
Food.objects.filter(FoodQuantity__quantity=self.quantity, id=self.id)[0].kcal
```

in shell it works... in application I get error:

```
"list index out of range"
```

---

Ive already solved the problem :)
Thanks!

Comment: Your shell must be targeting a different database.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Try using the first .first() method instead of the array index [0]. Probably won't fix your problem, but its better for catching errors.